# How To Write A TestClass For Trigger For Validation based on object field

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class, code-coverage

the below code is for validation of NEWS News__c object fields based on PROJECT Project__c object field ,the trigger is working fine but I have problem with my test class...  can anyone help me out with my test class , As im new to testing Apex code I'm unable to write it properly .

```
Trigger Trg_IntegrityIndexMerit on Project__c ( before update ) {

for( Project__c P : Trigger.New ){
    String PID = p.Id;
    Project__c P1=[select Id,Name,Status__r.Name, Value__c, ContractValue__c, Contract__r.Name, Country__c, Workflow__c, CreatedDate,Scope__c  from Project__c where Id=:PID];
    String sScopeReplace;
    List<News__c> News= [select Id,Date__c,Name from News__c where Project__c=:PID];
    if ( News.Size(  ) >0 ){
        for( News__c N :News ){
         if( Status=='Study' &&  !( sContract=='Design Build (DB)' ) ){//PROJECT FIELDS
         if( N.Date__c > date.today(  ) +90 && N.Date__c < date.today(  ) +97 ){ // NEWS FIELDS

          sErrorComments +='Status-Study Should be within 90 days from today for News Record-' + N.Name + '\r\n'; 

                }
                else if ( N.Date__c > date.today(  ) +97 ){

                    sErrorComments +='Status Study as exceeded 97 days from today for News Record-' + N.Name + '\r\n';                                         

                }


            }

        }

    }
```

TEST CLASS

```
    @isTest 
Public class testIntegrity{
    public static void init()
    {
        List <Project__c> proj = New List<Project__c>();

        //Project__c sproj=[select Id,Name,Status__r.Name, Value__c, ContractValue__c, Contract__r.Name, Country__c, Workflow__c, CreatedDate,Scope__c  from Project__c where Id=:PID];
        //Static String PID = sporj.Id;
        //Static String Status = sproj.Status__r.Name;
        //Static String sContract =sproj.Contract__r.Name;
        //Static String sContractValue =String.Valueof(sproj.ContractValue__c);

    }

    @isTest Static void testinsertproject(  )
    {
        init();   
        List <Project__c> proj = New List<Project__c>(  );
        Project__c sproj = New Project__c(  );
        sproj.Parent__c = 'a042000000IPjwg';

        sproj.Inactive__c=true;
        sproj.Value__c=400;
        sproj.ContractValue__c=40;
        sproj.Contract__c='a0I200000089UBU';
        sproj.Contract_Type_MCI__c='Build';
        sproj.Brownfield__c=false;
        sproj.Offshore__c=false;
        insert sproj;


        News__c sobj = New News__c(  );
        sobj.Inactive__c = false;
        sobj.News__c = 'fsfsfdsgsddsf';
        sobj.Date__c = Date.valueOf( '20-10-2017' );
        sobj.Source_Type__c ='Primary';
        sobj.Number_of_Updates__c ='2';
        sobj.Project__c = sobj.Id;
        insert sobj;



        if( sproj.Status__c =='Study' && !( sproj.Contract__c=='Design Build (DB)' ) )
        {
            String spro = String.valueof( sproj.Id );
            if( sobj.Date__c>date.today(  ) +90 && sobj.Date__c<date.today(  ) +97 )
            {


            }

            else if( sobj.Date__c > date.today(  )+97 )
            {
                //do nothing 

            }



        }






    }


}
```

Comment: What part of it isn't working?  Can you be more clear on what the exact problem is?

Comment: you shouldn't be using Ids in your Test class, because if you pass to production, maybe the Id your using doesn't existe(or you can delete the record you're referencing in your Test). And also, a best practice for your Test class is creating your Own data for test, and not using the data already exist in the org

Comment: Be sure you checked well your unit test class. From what I see your tigger class will execute "before update", whether in your test class peforms insert and not update.